# Equivalent of "Google Closure Compiler" for HTML?

Tags: html, minify, google-closure, google-closure-compiler

Is there an equivalent of Google's [Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) for HTML minimizing?

Answer (score 1):

I presume you mean the Closure compiler, which effectively compresses javascript.  If you search [the goog](http://google.com) for "HTML Compressor", you will find a lot of options catering to individual needs.

Answer (score 1):

Consider HTML Tidy:

http://infohound.net/tidy/

It's a free tool that does a great job.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try google's mod_pagespeed, which will minify the response content.

Answer (score 1):

I write a python script, replace all id and class name at pushlish. The script generate unique token for each class name and id, relpace the in both javascript,css and html template file. It workds greate for me

Answer (score 0):

I am using [Minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/) to trim and compress the html at runtime. The only requirements and setup are that you put [Minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/) on your server and prepend the following code to the page.

```
<?php require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/min/pageBuffer.php'; ?>
<!-- html -->
```